# Mongodb - E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example of my MongoDb structure :

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "children" : [ 
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "status" : "     fsdfsdf           "
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "status" : "        ffdfg       "
        }, 
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "status" : "   fsdfsdfsdfdsf          "
        }
    ]
}
```

I wanted to trim records in mongodb, so i did :

```
db.getCollection('myCollectionName').find().forEach(function (doc){
  for (subDoc of doc.children) {
    if(typeof subDoc.status === 'string') {
      subDoc.theText = subDoc.theText.trim();
    }
  }
  db.getCollection('myCollectionName').save(doc);
})
```

But i got this error :

E QUERY SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Answer (score 2):

You use wrong identifier — the array item doesn't have `theText` identifier.

```
var docs = db.getCollection('myCollectionName').find()

docs.forEach(function (doc) {
    for (subDoc of doc.children) {
        if(typeof subDoc.status === 'string') {
          subDoc.status = subDoc.status.trim();
        }
    }

    db.getCollection('myCollectionName').save(doc);
})
```

#### Step by Step instructions

Open local mongo shell with db stackoverflow

```
⋊> ~ mongo stackoverflow
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/stackoverflow
MongoDB server version: 3.4.0
```

Insert one (your) document

```
> db.getCollection('myCollectionName').insertOne({
...     "id" : 1,
...     "children" : [
...         {
...             "id" : 2,
...             "status" : "     fsdfsdf           "
...         },
...         {
...             "id" : 3,
...             "status" : "        ffdfg       "
...         },
...         {
...             "id" : 4,
...             "status" : "   fsdfsdfsdfdsf          "
...         }
...     ]
... })
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("588b4984522a4f31ff6bc738")
}
```

Find inserted document

```
> db.getCollection('myCollectionName').findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588b4984522a4f31ff6bc738"),
    "id" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "status" : "     fsdfsdf           "
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "status" : "        ffdfg       "
        },
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "status" : "   fsdfsdfsdfdsf          "
        }
    ]
}
```

I use `findOne` because I know in db only one document. In normal situation you need use `find` and `pretty` to find all document in collection

```
> db.getCollection('myCollectionName').find().pretty()
```

Find documents in collection and save cursor in variable

```
> var docs = db.getCollection('myCollectionName').find()
```

Run function for trim **only** field `status` in array `children` in documents

```
> docs.forEach(function (doc) {
...     for (subDoc of doc.children) {
...         if(typeof subDoc.status === 'string') {
...           subDoc.status = subDoc.status.trim();
...         }
...     }
...
...     db.getCollection('myCollectionName').save(doc);
... })
```

> Improvement for *production*: find only documents with field children and check fields into document exists.

Check the result (find the document)

```
> db.getCollection('myCollectionName').findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("588b4984522a4f31ff6bc738"),
    "id" : 1,
    "children" : [
        {
            "id" : 2,
            "status" : "fsdfsdf"
        },
        {
            "id" : 3,
            "status" : "ffdfg"
        },
        {
            "id" : 4,
            "status" : "fsdfsdfsdfdsf"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Add step by step instructions. Try do the same on your local mongo.